# How use correct filter in Timeseries DataStudio ? - BiqQuery

Tags: looker-studio

I am playing with Datastudio.
I have these data from BigQuery:

```
Row,country,date,confirmed  
1,Afghanistan,2020-03-16,21
2,Afghanistan,2020-03-17,22
3,Afghanistan,2020-03-18,22
...
```

TimeSeries Chart is showing OK, but optional Filter is showing wrong "Confirmed Cases"...
It shows probably sum of all cases by country, and not the last number of cases by last date.
Check my screenshots, or u can check the chart oniine here

https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/28caf33b-346a-4e5b-b726-175b08f23e95/page/cm3NB

Also there is maybe some options how to create extra filter by date, but my data is updating every day, so is there any options how to deal with this in DataStudio in my case ?

Another issue is that when I create new report, everytime I got this error>
User Configuration Error -This data source was improperly configured

[image]
[image]

[image]

Thanks for any help

Andrew

Comment: I am not sure if this is even possible to fix, because problem is that my table <confirmed cases> in timeframe contains every day total number of cases, but internal logic in DataStudio expect that every fields represent new value, so Total number is SUM (wrong number)
But I am sure that this is not just my case when somebody is working with TimeSeries Charts so question is how to fix it, if possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally I fixed tha main issue with this [image]>